# How java allows to add Integer and Double instance?

Tags: java, wrapper

What internally happens at the 3rd line when I execute the following code

```
Integer i=1; 
Double d1=1.1; 
Double d2= i+d1;
```

Answer (score 11):

You can read the definition of "internal" workings in the language spec:

- [Numeric addition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2)
- [Simple Assignment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1)

But these might be a bit dry.

Try decompiling the following code:

```
void add(Integer i, Double d1) {
  Double d2= i+d1;
}
```

This is compiled to:

```
  void add(java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Double);
    Code:
       0: aload_1
       1: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
       4: i2d
       5: aload_2
       6: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/Double.doubleValue:()D
       9: dadd
      10: invokestatic  #5                  // Method java/lang/Double.valueOf:(D)Ljava/lang/Double;
      13: astore_3
      14: return
```

Breaking it down line-by-line (for the significant lines, anyway):

- 1: This is unboxing `i` from `Integer` to `int`
- 4: This is widening the `int` value of `i` to `double`
- 6: This is unboxing `d1` from `Double` to `double`
- 9: This is adding the unboxed (and widened) values.
- 10: This is boxing the result from `double` to `Double`.

You can see this as being equivalent to:

```
void add2(Integer i, Double d1) {
  Double d2= Double.valueOf((double) i.intValue() + d1.doubleValue());
}
```

since the two have identical bytecode.

Answer (score 2):

On every arithmetic operation in Java the result is at least int. If any operand is bigger than int the result is the same type of the bigger operand. On the third line, i is unboxed and promoted to double, and added to the unboxed value of d1. Then the result is boxed into d2.

Comment: Careful in the use of the word "bigger": the converted type is neither based upon magnitude of the value, nor the width of the data type. The operands are converted to double, float or long (if either operand is that type) or int otherwise, in that order of preference. Note that long is wider than float, but takes lower precedence.

Answer (score 1):

> How java allows to add Integer and Double instance?

Wrapper objects (Integer, Double, Float, etc...) cannot be direct target of arithmetical operators such as `+` or `-`.
Only primitives may be target of these operators.

But since java 5, Java allows to convert automatically an `Integer` to an `int` and do the reverse with auto-boxing.

So here :

```
Integer i=1; 
Double d1=1.1; 
Double d2= i+d1;
```

The third line can be divided in two steps:

- `i+d1`, the  `Double d1` and the `Integer i` are converted to their counterpart primitive (unboxing operation). Which allows to make the addition (`1 + 1.1`) that produces a `double` primitive value.
- and here `Double d2=i+d1;` the result of this `double` primitive is converted to a `Double` object (boxing).